# Meteor and Telescope - How can I fully change the language in Telescope?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I did go to the setting panel and change the language to Vietnamese. However, a lot of them were still in English. Is there a best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you look here: https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/i18n/vn.i18n.json. I believe this is the Vietnamese translation `json` file. What you could do is make a pull request and add in more translations, if your pull request gets merged then you will have updated the Vietnamese translations for telescope :). You could also build telescope from [source](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope) and add in the translations. Make sense?